# How to specify a type argument is the type of the derived class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core

I have a class that looks something like this.

```
public abstract class Parsable
{
    public bool ParseField<T, TMember>(Expression<Func<T, TMember>> expression, string s)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is there any way to specify that the `T` type argument for the `ParseField()` method is always the same type as the derived class?

I'm happy to drop the type argument if there is another way to write this where the given expression is always of the derived type.

Note: The intent is to use this method like this:

```
public class PurchaseOrder : Parseable
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    public int Field3 { get; set; }
}

PurchaseOrder po = new();
po.ParseField(x => x.Field1, "1");
po.ParseField(x => x.Field2, "2");
po.ParseField(x => x.Field3, "3");
```

Comment: In the absence of any other solution, you could add a `new ParseField` method to each derived class that invokes the base method with the appropriate generic type argument.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: Yes, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid to make things as foolproof as possible.

Comment: Any particular reason why you prefer generics instead of polymorphism? You could just change `expression` to be of type `Func<Parsable, TMember>`. Also, doesn't `where T : Parsable` do exactly what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the derived class a generic parameter of the base class. This is a pattern more commonly seen in C++ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) but the following code compiles in C# as well:

```
public abstract class Parsable<T> where T : Parsable<T>
{
    public bool ParseField<TMember>(Expression<Func<T, TMember>> expression, string s)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class PurchaseOrder : Parsable<PurchaseOrder>
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    public int Field3 { get; set; }
}

public static class SomeClass
{
    public static void DoTheThing()
    {
        PurchaseOrder po = new();
        po.ParseField(x => x.Field1, "1");
        po.ParseField(x => x.Field2, "2");
        po.ParseField(x => x.Field3, "3");
    }
}
```